# Simple number pad in javascript reset

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('body').on('click', '.num_pad_wrap div', function() {

  if ($('#ticket_number').text() == '0' && $('#ticket_number').text() != 'C') {
    $('#ticket_number').empty();
  }

  var pressed = ($(this).find('span').text() == 'C') ? $('#ticket_number').text('0') : $(this).find('span').text();
  $('#ticket_number').append(pressed);


});
```

```css
.num_pad_wrap div {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ticket_number">0</div>
<div class="num_pad_wrap">
  <div><span>1</span></div>
  <div><span>2</span></div>
  <div><span>3</span></div>
  <div><span>4</span></div>
  <div><span>5</span></div>
  <div><span>6</span></div>
  <div><span>7</span></div>
  <div><span>8</span></div>
  <div><span>9</span></div>
  <div><span>0</span></div>
  <div><span>C</span></div>
</div>
```

How can I do a limit for my above num pad? Assume user inserted value which is more than 50, the result should be 50, and if the user click on any key again, it will function as usual again. I don't want it to be reset to zero to avoid extra one click.

Comment: what is 50? length or Value?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi value.

Comment: Do `if (parseInt($('#ticket_number').val()) > 50){ //do stuff }`

Comment: @ParthTrivedi it's not as simple as that, look at below answer, it doesn't work. here https://jsfiddle.net/etbkgnbL/

Comment: what is your problem now

Comment: @ParthTrivedi try to use the numpad, u will find the problem

Comment: every time you resetted it to 50. and again doing entering to number pad. what do you want now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101172/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-jennifer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
$('body').on('click', '.num_pad_wrap div', function() {

    if ($('#ticket_number').text() == '0' || $('#ticket_number').text() == '50') {
        $('#ticket_number').empty();
    }

    var pressed = ($(this).find('span').text() == 'C') ? $('#ticket_number').text('0') : $(this).find('span').text();

    $('#ticket_number').append(pressed);

    if ($('#ticket_number').text() > 50) {
        $('#ticket_number').text('50');
    }

});
```

Comment: My bad, the last "});" was missing from the code block. Try again.